# Group and Merge elements in same list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a hotels list, each hotel has an Id, is possible to have the same hotel (same id) duplicated but with different rooms cotisations.  I want to merge the duplicate elements in one with LINQ, replacing all the attributes except the rooms which must to add to the another list. I try to reach it using foreach:

```
private List<Domain.CheckRateDomain.Hotels> BuildResponseResult(List<Hotels> hotelsList)
{
    var listResult = new List<Hotels>();
    var hotelListAux = new List<Hotels>(hotelsList);

    foreach (var hotel in hotelsList)
    {
        hotelListAux.Remove(hotel);

        foreach (var hotelAux in hotelListAux)
        {
            if (hotel.Id == hotelAux.Id)
            {
                hotel.Rooms.AddRange(hotelAux.Rooms);
                listResult.Add(hotel);
            }
            else
            {
                listResult.Add(hotel);
                listResult.Add(hotelAux);
            }
        }
    }

    return hotelsList;
}
```

Comment: Can you simply provide a sample list what your collection looks like and also the desired output? Your question is not clear at this stage.

Comment: Yeah, I think what might assist here is a brief example of what is going in and then what you expect to get out. Something in a simple table form would greatly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GroupBy:

```
hotelsList.GroupBy(h => h.Id)
     .Select(g => new Hotel
          {
              Id = g.Key,
              Rooms = g.SelectMany(h => h.Rooms).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listResult = new List<Hotels>();

            var results = listResult.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => new {
                hotel = x.FirstOrDefault(),
                cotisations = x.Select(y => y.rooms).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            //then set original rooms to null
            foreach(var h in results)
            {
                h.hotel.rooms = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Hotels :
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Room> rooms { get; set;}

    }
    public class Room
    {

    }
}
```